# Pact Gradle state url response

Tags: gradle, pact

I am using pact with gradle.
Is it possible to capture the response from state change URL?
For example, I am adding a new record to the database. The provider creates a unique id which has to be used for other operations on that record.

So, I would use provider state change to call API to create the record and the unique Id is sent back in the response. Is it possible to capture this unique Id and use it for other pact verification tasks?

Also, I know pact allows us to modify the headers for the pact verification request. Is it possible to modify the request body too?

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a feature request issue in https://github.com/dius/pact-jvm

I do not believe you can currently modify the response. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Thanks. Pact is not meant for our use case. We wanted to use a key generated by the application during interaction 1 with interaction 2.

Comment: You are correct - Pact is not designed for this use case. Each interaction is (by design) intended to be completely independent of any other interaction - the order of replay is actually random in some implementations. You should use provider states to set up the required state on the provider.